# Let $u = [1,4,3], v = [1,−1,1]$ be linearly independent vectors and let $w = [−1,k,−5], k \in \Bbb R$.

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $k$ is the set $\{ u,v,w \}$ linearly dependent and for what values of $k$ is the set linearly independent?
I have been trying to solve this problem by row echelon method, but I get the vectors to be linearly independent even if I include $k$. Because in the calculations , $k$ cancels out . Please help me with this .

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: You should give a full (self-contained) problem statement in the body of the Question, not relying only on the title to present essential parts of the setup or the goal of the problem.  One way that linear dependence could occur is for $w$ to be a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.  You might be able to work out in your head what value of $k$ will make this happen.  It isn't clear why "if I include $k$", that "$k$ cancels out."  More explicit details of what this means would improve your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do that is to figure out for what values the determinant is $0$. Then excluding all of them you will have the values of k for which determinant is non-zero. Hence Rowspace has dim 3 . and you have your linear independence . If you see carefully...then by directly computing the determinant you will have that for $k=-9$ you have the determinant is $0$. Hence for $k\neq -9$ you have your required linear independence.

If you proceed by RREF. Then I would suggest taking the matrix as :-

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 4 & 3\\
-1&k&-5
\end{bmatrix}$$

Apply $R_{2}-R_{1}$ and $R_{3}+R_{1}$

You get :-
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 5 & 2\\
0&k-1&-4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Apply $R_{2}/5$

You get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & \frac{2}{5}\\
0&k-1&-4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now apply $R_{1}+R_{2}$ and $R_{3}-(k-1)R_{2}$
You get:-

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{7}{5}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{2}{5}\\
0&0&-4-\frac{2(k-1)}{5}
\end{bmatrix}$$

So you see that the last row is zero if $-4-\frac{2(k-1)}{5}=0$

So it happens for $k=-9$.

So if $k\neq -9$ . You have linear independence. And for $k=-9$ you have linear dependence.

However I would recommend just calculating the determinant of the matirx and setting it to $0$ and figuring out for what $k$ that happens rather than going for RREF , especially if the field is of real numbers. It is way quicker and easier.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Gandalf Sauron. I will try this way ….

Comment: If it satisfies your query try marking it as the answer.

Comment: Mr.Gandalf Sauron , are we not supposed take the transpose of what u took as the matrix?

Comment: It does not matter. The span of the row space is the same as the span of the column space. When you take the transpose then you get the span of the column vectors. But guess what....column vectors are the row vectors transposed. Oh and also you can interchange the order of the way the vectors are written. Because in reality what you are doing is solving the system of equations $c_{1}u+c_{2}v+c_{3}w=0$ And checking that whether these 3 gives a non-zero solution or a unique zero solution. In the first case they will be dependent and in the 2nd case we have independence.

Comment: And also no. Since you are trying to find the RREF you have to take the row vectors as the vectors you want to work with. If you want to reduce to a Column reduced echelon form then you can take the column vectors ( or the transpose of the matrix). But in any case, the row rank = column rank.